# Problems with performance of static query vs. stored procedure

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have two, near identical, queries, The first being a static query, with variables, and the second a stored procedure, with input parameters.

**Static Query**

```
DECLARE @GLNumber INT = 1043
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '1/1/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '4/20/2015'

    SELECT 
        T1.EMPLOYEE         AS [Empolyee Number],
        T2.LAST_NAME        AS [Last Name],
        T2.FIRST_NAME       AS [First Name],
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT    AS [Distribution Account Unit],
        T3.DESCRIPTION,
        SUM(T1.WAGE_AMOUNT) AS [Wage Amount]    
    FROM 
        JOBCODE T3, 
        EMPLOYEE T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        PRTIME T1 ON 
            T2.COMPANY = T1.COMPANY and 
            T2.EMPLOYEE = T1.EMPLOYEE
    WHERE 
        T1.DIST_COMPANY = @GLNumber and 
        CONVERT(DATE, TR_DATE, 101) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
        T1.PAY_SUM_GRP in ('TPC', 'TDS') and 
        T2.JOB_CODE = T3.JOB_CODE and 
        T2.COMPANY = T3.COMPANY
    GROUP BY
        T1.EMPLOYEE,
        T2.LAST_NAME,
        T2.FIRST_NAME,
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT,
        T3.DESCRIPTION
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
(
    @GLNumber INT = NULL,
    @StartDate DATE = NULL,
    @EndDate DATE = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        T1.EMPLOYEE         AS [Empolyee Number],
        T2.LAST_NAME        AS [Last Name],
        T2.FIRST_NAME       AS [First Name],
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT    AS [Distribution Account Unit],
        T3.DESCRIPTION,
        SUM(T1.WAGE_AMOUNT) AS [Wage Amount]    
    FROM 
        JOBCODE T3, 
        EMPLOYEE T2 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        PRTIME T1 ON 
            T2.COMPANY = T1.COMPANY and 
            T2.EMPLOYEE = T1.EMPLOYEE
    WHERE 
        T1.DIST_COMPANY = @GLNumber and 
        CONVERT(DATE, TR_DATE, 101) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
        T1.PAY_SUM_GRP in ('TPC', 'TDS') and 
        T2.JOB_CODE = T3.JOB_CODE and 
        T2.COMPANY = T3.COMPANY
    GROUP BY
        T1.EMPLOYEE,
        T2.LAST_NAME,
        T2.FIRST_NAME,
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT,
        T3.DESCRIPTION
END
```

As I am sure you can see, the biggest difference between the two queries is that the first runs off of declared variables, while the second uses input parameters.

Both queries return the same, correct, results. However, running the static query on my system takes less than 1 second, while executing the stored procedure from my system takes upwards of 3 1/2 minutes.

I do not understand why there is such a discrepancy between execution times between the static query and the stored procedure (I would expect the execution times to be similar, especially on such a simple query).

**What are the potential reasons that I could be experiencing such a discrepancy in efficiency?**

I understand that stored procedures do not, generally, offer performance advantages against static queries, however, I have never experienced a stored procedure perform this poorly when compared to the static query.

Is there any way to correct this performance issue? I am operating on SQL Server 2008 R2, SP1.

**Clarification**
When running the stored procedures, I am passing in the same parameters as being used in the static query.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried adding `WITH RECOMPILE` to the procedure but it had no affect. I additionally tried `WITH (NOLOCK)` on the tables but again, no affect.

Comment: `WITH (NOLOCK)` will have no effect on parameter sniffing. Try adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the query. Though it is also possible that the parameter values being sniffed are the same as the ones you are executing with and the statistics need updating.

Comment: Thanks, neither the `option (recompile)` nor updating statistics on the database helped, however, I found that by reordering my FROM/WHERE statements, I was able to get the correct results from the stored procedure in under 1 second, as I did with the static query. I am posting the updated query as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to solve this by updating the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses in the query. Essentially, for some reason, the stored procedure did not like using a comma in place of `INNER JOIN ... ON`. This brought the execution time on the stored procedure down to under a second.

The finalized procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rptTipReport_ByCompany]
(
    @GLNumber INT = NULL,
    @StartDate DATE = NULL,
    @EndDate DATE = NULL
) 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 
        T1.EMPLOYEE         AS [Empolyee Number],
        T2.LAST_NAME        AS [Last Name],
        T2.FIRST_NAME       AS [First Name],
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT    AS [Distribution Account Unit],
        T3.DESCRIPTION,
        SUM(T1.WAGE_AMOUNT) AS [Wage Amount]    
    FROM 
        PROD90.dbo.PRTIME T1 
        LEFT JOIN PROD90.dbo.EMPLOYEE T2 on T1.EMPLOYEE = T2.EMPLOYEE
        INNER JOIN PROD90.dbo.JOBCODE T3 on T2.JOB_CODE = T3.JOB_CODE

    WHERE 
        T1.DIST_COMPANY = @GLNumber and 
        CONVERT(DATE, TR_DATE, 101) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND
        T1.PAY_SUM_GRP in ('TPC', 'TDS') 
    GROUP BY
        T1.EMPLOYEE,
        T2.LAST_NAME,
        T2.FIRST_NAME,
        T1.DST_ACCT_UNIT,
        T3.DESCRIPTION
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In the static version, the variables for StartDate and EndDate have been assigned values.

In the SP version, they are NULL.

The SP version must run over the entire date range of data, while the static version can operate (potentially using an index) over just the relevant date range.

Comment: Those are default values. Presumably the OP is passing the same actual parameter values into the proc from outside or this question would be pointless.

Comment: Yes, I am passing the same parameters into the stored procedure as in the static query

Comment: Can you create a `[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data so we can see the schema, indexes and code. Even if the sample data is relatively small, it may still show slower execution time for the SP,